# How can I make an element fade out when a particluar percentage of a div is scrolled to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an image that I've positioned: sticky; that is also animated to fade in and fade out at 6s intervals. I want the animated image to disappear completely when the parent div is scrolled to, say 90%. I've seen scripts that control fade out at a certain pixel amount from the top of the page (or div), but that won't work since the parent div's height is content dependent (and changes on every device size), I need it to be controlled by a designated percentage, not a static pixel amount.

Comment: Could you show us some of your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as though `intersectionObserver` Would be helpful here.

You can set it so that when a percentage of an element is in view you can do something. This is set via a threshold option.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API for detail.

If you post your code we have a look to see how this might help.

**UPDATE:** Taking the code given this snippet places a 10% high div absolutely positioned over the bottom of the text and observes when it goes in and when it goes out of the viewport.

**FURTHER UPDATE** the green square is made to fade out when we are towards the bottom by adding another set of keyframes, disappear.

```js
let observation = (entries, observer) => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {document.querySelector('.an-inner-box').style.animation = 'disappear 3s forwards 1';}// it's in view do something as we are near the bottom
    else { document.querySelector('.an-inner-box').style.animation = 'emerge 6s forwards infinite';} // it's gone out of view so do something as we are not near the bottom
  }
)};
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(observation, {});// no options needed as default will trigger observer on as little as 1px overlap and viewport is the default
let observed = document.querySelector('.observed');
observer.observe(observed);

/* I don't know what this does so have commented out for now. Reinstate if required of course.
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".an-inner-box").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 1100);
  });*/
```

```css
.a-container {
 position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: pink;
}

.an-outer-box {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 10%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: red;
}

.an-inner-box {
  position: sticky;
  top: 40px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: lime;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  opacity: 1;
  animation: emerge 6s forwards infinite;
  
}

@keyframes emerge {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    50%{
      opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

@keyframes disappear {
  100% {
       opacity: 0;
    }
}

.text {
  font-size: 36px;
  width: 100%
  height: auto;
  z-index: 2;
}

.observed {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 10%;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="a-container">
<div class ="an-outer-box">
  <div class="an-inner-box"></div>
  </div>
<div class="text">
lots of text here coweoicnwe coinc weocw own oefn won fon ofnwofimc oewncoe fnewo now nfowc ocroorfn rockm km erocn on orcnorcnorc rocn ron o gnfn rovnreo rno rcn orfn ro nvonero nro n on ornfa ovm orn qornv ofnr ofrn owrenv eorfnqw vpofnv on oerfnq ocn orinq3ponow nvr vornv orfn qwonq onw oervn ov n wofn rogne og nqogn nrowro nvo rghq3orp irogn qrovn qrvnr wovnro gnq3r orvn rvnr oanv owrvnqw ropnrq ogring aowrnv ovn reognr gon own ownv eorvnq orwn owrnworn aovnefovenr orp nvero vneov nefon qeovnerov n gpwnvan;va rvoiaernv ae;fvn erov ner;vn s;v narinovrng 3orn veovn  g[ 3q]g jap q30v eoi rogh0[ n3om iq3v30530qvmv[pq rhm350[5m haq3 3i 4m q0[4gm q30m q3ivmq3p gmq3 [vm35gq3m50vqm [3m q30 q50[g 350 mq[g m30[ m 5054vq35035q[0h ]3q 3vq3[q35g9jq35]- 3 vm350gj35[ y9v 50[5ivmq 3-gj 3]-t9 3]mq35 -[g9 jq353pgq3]-rm q3-m3 [q3mq3 q35m-[yj q35y]]]]]]]]]]]
lots of text here coweoicnwe coinc weocw own oefn won fon ofnwofimc oewncoe fnewo now nfowc ocroorfn rockm km erocn on orcnorcnorc rocn ron o gnfn rovnreo rno rcn orfn ro nvonero nro n on ornfa ovm orn qornv ofnr ofrn owrenv eorfnqw vpofnv on oerfnq ocn orinq3ponow nvr vornv orfn qwonq onw oervn ov n wofn rogne og nqogn nrowro nvo rghq3orp irogn qrovn qrvnr wovnro gnq3r orvn rvnr oanv owrvnqw ropnrq ogring aowrnv ovn reognr gon own ownv eorvnq orwn owrnworn aovnefovenr orp nvero vneov nefon qeovnerov n gpwnvan;va rvoiaernv ae;fvn erov ner;vn s;v narinovrng 3orn veovn  g[ 3q]g jap q30v eoi rogh0[ n3om iq3v30530qvmv[pq rhm350[5m haq3 3i 4m q0[4gm q30m q3ivmq3p gmq3 [vm35gq3m50vqm [3m q30 q50[g 350 mq[g m30[ m 5054vq35035q[0h ]3q 3vq3[q35g9jq35]- 3 vm350gj35[ y9v 50[5ivmq 3-gj 3]-t9 3]mq35 -[g9 jq353pgq3]-rm q3-m3 [q3mq3 q35m-[yj q35y]]]]]]]]]]]
 lots of text here coweoicnwe coinc weocw own oefn won fon ofnwofimc oewncoe fnewo now nfowc ocroorfn rockm km erocn on orcnorcnorc rocn ron o gnfn rovnreo rno rcn orfn ro nvonero nro n on ornfa ovm orn qornv ofnr ofrn owrenv eorfnqw vpofnv on oerfnq ocn orinq3ponow nvr vornv orfn qwonq onw oervn ov n wofn rogne og nqogn nrowro nvo rghq3orp irogn qrovn qrvnr wovnro gnq3r orvn rvnr oanv owrvnqw ropnrq ogring aowrnv ovn reognr gon own ownv eorvnq orwn owrnworn aovnefovenr orp nvero vneov nefon qeovnerov n gpwnvan;va rvoiaernv ae;fvn erov ner;vn s;v narinovrng 3orn veovn  g[ 3q]g jap q30v eoi rogh0[ n3om iq3v30530qvmv[pq rhm350[5m haq3 3i 4m q0[4gm q30m q3ivmq3p gmq3 [vm35gq3m50vqm [3m q30 q50[g 350 mq[g m30[ m 5054vq35035q[0h ]3q 3vq3[q35g9jq35]- 3 vm350gj35[ y9v 50[5ivmq 3-gj 3]-t9 3]mq35 -[g9 jq353pgq3]-rm q3-m3 [q3mq3 q35m-[yj q35y]]]]]]]]]]] 
  </div>
  <div class="observed"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've read a lot about intersection observers and I suspect you are right. I've not been able to get them to work for me in other animations where I've tried to use them. Here is a pen that I created that is an approximation of what I'm attempting to do. https://codepen.io/ehbehr/pen/yLVNwEj The script is from Nick Ciliak https://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/sfutl and modified by me to be a facsimile of what want to do. The code didn't work on the animation itself, so I put it into a parent div that would be transparent in real life.

Comment: Is it OK to add a little HTML? If we put an absolutely positioned div at the bottom with 10% height we could perhaps observe that coming and going in and out of the viewport.

Comment: I took a chance and have put up a snippet which enters a callback on the bottom 10% going in or out of the viewport.

Comment: wow. thanks. I see it working in the snippet as you describe. Curiously, when I comment out my own html and css and replace it all with yours, it doesn't console log anything in my pen. Beyond that, I'm unsure of how your if/else statements translate. Your "if" says "do something" and your "else" says "do something different" whereas, in my case, "if" (not near bottom) says "don't hide the animation (or its div)" and my "else" is "hide the animation (or its div)", not "hide or show something else." How would using the same animation name for both conditions render opposite results?

Comment: Our if/elses are probably just the other way round from each other. JS returns true when the div is seen (ie enters the viewport) and so the code you need to put in the if is whatever you want to do when you scroll down to near the bottom, and the else is, well, the code you want to do when you aren't near the bottom. Do you want to share your codepen as I can't see why you aren't getting console logs.

Comment: Sure, that would be great. It is the link above and here, also https://codepen.io/ehbehr/pen/yLVNwEj Do I need to do something more than provide the link for you to be able to edit it?

Comment: Using your codepen - unaltered - and going to my browser's dev tools console I am seeing 'not near bottom' 'near bottom' in the console OK. Are you not seeing it at all? What browser/OS are you using. I'm on Windows10 Edge/Chrome.

Comment: Ah, now I see it. I misunderstood where the console log would show up. I found it on Chrome for Mac and, yes it does log the event just as you said. So, you're saying that if I change {console.log('near bottom');} and {console.log(' not near bottom');} to "animation: emerge (etc.), that should work to hide the red parent of the green square's div? Or, is that syntax wrong? You've been such a huge help, I hate to keep bugging you, but thanks.

Comment: Do you just want to hide the green square, or the whole red parent?

Comment: Ideally, just the green square, but hiding its parent will hide it as well, so I'll take what I can get, but, yes, if we can hide just the square that'd be great. The idea behind putting it in a parent div was to enable me to absolutely position a sticky div at different heights below the top of the page, depending on the device in question.

Comment: I've edited the snippet just to set the green square to display: none as you get towards the bottom, and to reinstate it as you go back up. This is probably better than changing the opacity to 0 - the browser knows it doesn't have to bother with animating the square if display is none.

Comment: That is nearly perfect and you are my hero. One last thing and if there's no way to do this, I'll work around it. But would it be possible to get the green square to fade away when it reaches the designated height, rather than instantly disappear? I was hoping to make it look like it just doesn't blink back on when it gets to that point.

Comment: I've made it use an animation to fade out - currently set at 3 seconds but of course you can change that.

Comment: That is absolutely perfect! I don't know how to thank you enough. But I do know I'll be having all sorts of fun with intersection observers going forward. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

So this maybe isn't a perfect fix but the [WayPoints Library](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/) lets you embed a waypoint in your code so when you scroll past it it triggers a function. It defaults to the top of the window, but accepts an offset parameter **which can be a percentage**. Using this you can make it so a function is called at 90% scrolled.